# How to properly use Laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5.7

I have a web application for hockey simulation and I was wondering the use of my models recently. I don't know if I'm using my models the "good" way or should I say, the `laravel` way, and if there could be future repercussions that I didn't think of.

So for example, I have a lot of utility functions in my model. I have a `Team` model that can return the total salary of all players and also has a `getInjuredPlayers()` function to retrieve a list of all the injured players.

So my models declare de Eloquent relationships AND have some utility functions that are easily accessible directly in the view by doing stuff like: `$team->getInjuredPlayers();`.

I was wondering if its **OK** to do it like this or should I put my utility functions in the controller used for the desired view and only declare the relationships in the models.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since your utility functions interact with the database itself with no business logic except for fetching records, which is what a model is meant for, this is perfectly fine!

However,  don't use model variables inside a view. To maintain the purity of MVC, fetch the details from your model in your controller and pass that data as variables to your view blade file using `compact()`

Comment: I am actually using the `compact()` to pass my variables from my controllers to my views, I maybe explained it badly, I'm sorry, but thanks for the info, it reassures me alot. I was really wondering if I was using my models the good way. I actually tried it and found it really easier than getting always the infos in my controller and do all the stuff in the controller.

Comment: @ettdro yes, that also let's you have reusable code.

Comment: Indeed, haha and assure the coordination and validity of all data from that model.

Comment: [Not everybody agrees](https://laraveldaily.com/taylor-otwell-thin-controllers-fat-models-approach/) there should be no logic in the models